# Xui one API test form PHP

Tags: javascript, forms, api, contact-form, iptv

i want to give online test with xui one api via sms api contact form how can i do this

```
http://dns/accescode/?api_key=*****&action=create_line&is_trial=1&username=trialeapi&exp_date=1hour&bouquet=???&allowed_outputs=???
```

Hello

i want to give online test with xui one api via sms api contact form how can i do this

```
ex: curl "array( 'username' => $username, 'password' => $password, 'max_connections' => $max_connections, 'is_restreamer' => $reseller, 'exp_date' => $expire_date, 'bouquet' => json_encode( $bouquet_ids ) ) ); $opts = array( 'http' => array( 'method' => 'POST', 'header' => 'Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded', 'content' => http_build_query( $post_data ) ) ); $context = stream_context_create( $opts ); $api_result = json_decode( file_get_contents( $panel_url . "api.php?action=user&sub=create", false, $context ) ); ?>"
```

Example (API Success)

ex: curl "{"result":true,"created_id":14838,"username":"d4PSc5uCqF","password":"2ZiuRRZk4b"}"
The API returned as the username/password of the NEW line, as well as the ID so we can use it wherever we want.

Example(API Failed)

ex: curl "{"result":false,"error":"EXISTS"} {"result":false,"error":"PARAMETER ERROR"}"